# Uibutton touchupinside action breaks program in storyboard app

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, uibutton, storyboard

[image: Custom View For Picker]

I am trying to create a custom Picker view ,connected the touchupinside event to my PickerViewViewController.h class as funcion

```
- (IBAction)Done:(id)sender;
```

added funcion in .m

```
- (IBAction)Done:(id)sender {

 NSLog(@"Done");
```

}

Added the view to my main view as

```
 PickerViewViewController *pic=[self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"Pickerview"];
[self.view addSubview:pic.view];
```

[image: Custom Picker Instant Added]

but when i click done button it crashes ,i had done it before using XIB easily ,help?

Comment: You shouldn't add the view of another view controller to your view without making that controller a child view controller. The question though, is why do you want to add the picker from another controller, rather than just adding a picker view to your main controller's view?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all try renaming your function something like

```
- (IBAction)doneButtonPressed:(id)sender
```

Done might be reserved by the system for something (not sure, but it happened to me before)

You could just drop the storyboard ... and make a normal ViewController with a .xib :). Actually there is no need of a ViewController. Just make a UIView and a .xib linked to your UIView.

To attach a .xib to a UIView you can use:

```
+ (CustomViewName *)getNewCustomView {
NSArray *xib = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"CustomViewName" owner:nil options:nil];
for (NSObject *obj in xib) {
    if ([obj isKindOfClass:[CustomViewName class]]) {
        return (CustomViewName *)obj;
    }
}
return nil;
}
```

and intialise it like :

```
CustomViewName *customView = [CustomViewName getNewCustomView];
customView.frame = CGRectMake(...);
self.view addSubview:customView;
```

also in your .xib file you must set the name of your class ... but on the VIew not on the file's owner like so:

[image]

Comment: tried new name but still same , i had a similar problem when sub classed cells for table view ,when i tried to connect the button in cells to its class function it crashed .i think its because of storyboard do not know for sure how to escape this error

Comment: You could just drop the storyboard ... and make a normal ViewController with a .xib :)

Comment: cant drop storyboard in current project at this stage may be in next project.